# JdbcTemplate.queryXXX can't get the lastest data

Tags: unit-testing, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I have a SpringBoot program,There is a problem with one of my junit test case.
SpringBoot version:1.5.9.RELEASE
My code is like this

```
@Rollback
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PreloadJobApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PreloadProcessorServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    PreloadProcessorService testService;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private JobCalcOrderRepository jobCalcOrderRepository;

    @Test
    public void my_test_case() {
        CreateTestDataWithJdbcTemplate.save(JobPreloadSoEntity.builder()
                        ...
                        .build(),
                jdbcTemplate);

        testService.methodToTest();

//        List<JobCalcOrderEntity> jobOrders = jobCalcOrderRepository.findAll();
//        Assert.assertNotNull(jobOrders);
//        Assert.assertEquals(9, jobOrders.size());

        long jobCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from Job_Calc_Order", Long.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(9, jobCount);
    }
}
```

This code can get right result when run in IDEA with jdbcTemplate or jobCalcOrderRepository. But get zero when run in command line "gradle test"

I have try there ways:
1.Add Thread.sleep(5000) before read data.
2.Try to run queryForObject 3 times, and test the last result.
All failed.who can solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have known the reason.
In fact this test case is ok. but the other test case modify testService, and testService.methodToTest() failed to execute a sql, and then all data roll back. I find this reason by test log. I see this in log:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE TestTable SET PROCESS_FLAG = 2 WHERE id> 1 and id<= 101 ]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'TestTable'.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:416)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:440)
at com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.service.database.StageService.lambda$updateProcessFlag$18(StageService.java:280)
at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.forEach(HashMap.java:928)
```

and the "TestTable" is not a table which I want to use.
To solve this problem I remove the test case which modify testService.